# Aligning Social Media Share Icons

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using the DigG Digg Social Media Plugin for Wordpress using the manual code option:

My HTML is the following but this is not much use as its generated via PHP - I have implemented the media class and the boxes!

What my main issue is how can I get all the icons aligned via the same height?

[image]

[Live URL](http://hakatours.com/blog/merry-christmas-burto-claus)

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="diggSocialMedia">
            <div class="box0">
                <?php dd_fbshare_generate('Compact') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="box1">
                <?php dd_twitter_generate('Compact','hakatours') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <?php dd_fblike_generate('Like Button Count') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <?php dd_google1_generate('Compact') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should show the actual HTML output, not your PHP, since this all happens on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.diggSocialMedia > div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.diggSocialMedia {
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```